# React Single Page Application: Properly rendering different "pages"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, single-page-application

So I had a design pattern question I guess for React SPA's (single page application). Right now, we're using redux state to track which "page" the user is on. Depending on that page, we're rendering different html/css using conditionals (switch/ifelse).

I feel like it's a waste to create new components for something that isn't changing that much and while the variance in html/css per component varies ... I'm wondering if theres a better or "right" way to do this?

edit: After speaking with a fellow engineer, I think it makes sense to just conditionally render separate components. Although the abstraction to me seems kind of overkill it will probably be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Some people prefer to use React-router for what you're referring to, but I think it can also be up to you (if it works, it works, so-to-speak)

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-router and react-router-redux.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux

It can be connected with React and Redux. It offers an action creator (push) so you can dispatch router-like actions.